# Spring Boot JPA unknown column in field list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In MySQL I have script that create table

```
create table account (
AccountId int not null auto_increment,
Login varchar(31),
Password varchar(31),
primary key (AccountId)
);
```

In java class i have model to this table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Column(name = "AccountId", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer AccountId;
    private String  Login;
    private String Password;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getAccountId() {
        return AccountId;
    }
```

In Repository package

```
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Integer> {
    Account findAccountByLoginAndPassword(String login, String password);
}
```

In client site i try send in request login and password but i have error in server site

```
2018-05-28 14:46:15.464  INFO 20300 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select account0_.account_id as account_1_0_, account0_.login as login2_0_, account0_.password as password3_0_ from account account0_ where account0_.login=? and account0_.password=?

`ERROR 20300 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'account0_.account_id' in 'field list`
```

'
That mean I should change my column name in MySQL table to account_id?

Comment: in my case since I wanted to keep the non-conventional naming, same as what is there in the Entity class, this worked for me:

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"That means I should change my column name in MySQL table to account_id"

Yep, this is a good idea because of naming convention, but also you can configure proper naming strategy:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

Or you can try to print your column name in lower case. (If your MySQL is Windows based)

```
@Column(name="accountid", nullable = false, unique = true)
```

Comment: I change name column to lower case and also add @Column(name="accountid", nullable = false, unique = true) and it's work in my properties file I don't change strategy. Thanks you save my time

Answer (score 4):

Use `@Column(name="accountid", nullable = false, unique = true)`
Columns in Mysql are case insensitive. If you use case sensitive column name in `@Column` then it will convert camel case to snake case.

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate5 and Spring boot 1.5 or higher, If you still get "unknown column" error even after using **PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl** as naming strategy, try using @Column mapping on getter method of the field instead of property level @column mapping.

Comment: This still didn't work for me actually. I'm quite stuck on this with my naming and use of embedded Primary Key!